# Download and encode HTML page into file

Tags: c#, .net, file, webclient

I like to download some web pages which use charset="UTF-8"
This page is a sample: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billboard_Year-End_Hot_100_singles_of_2003
I always end up with special characters like this:
BeyoncÃ© instead of Beyoncé
I tried the following code:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
webClient.DownloadFile(url, fileName);
```

or this one:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Byte[] pageData = client.DownloadData(url);
string pageHtml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(pageData);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, pageHtml);
```

What do I do wrong?
I just want an easy way to download web pages and write them to files. After that is done I will extract data from these files and obviously I want "normal" characters like I see on the original web-page and not some special characters.

Comment: Encoding as Unicode worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the WriteAllText Method don't write the encoded Text in UTF-8 in the File.
You should add the Encoding:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, pageHtml, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works, but I am confused why it works. If I use your code:
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, pageHtml, Encoding.UTF8);
It works.  
But if I use this code (all the rest is the same):
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, pageHtml, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode);  
It also works. 
The first code creates a “normal” file with the correct spelling. The second code also creates a file with the correct spelling but the file is double the size and Unicode.

Comment: @Edgar in UTF-8 the eight stand for the number of bits used to encode a character i.e. 8 bits. Unicode uses 16 bits to encode a character. So UTF8 file re-encoded as Unicode will be double the size.

Comment: Big T, I understand the part about double the size and Unicode. What confuses me that the parameter "Encoding.UTF8" produces "normal" text and not UTF-8 encoded text.